# Can I open multidimesional model in Visual studio from SAP BW Query?

Tags: visual-studio, ssas, analysis, olap, sap-bw

I have installed Visual Studio 2017 with SSDT extension.
There is a Query (on OLAP) in SAP BW. I can connect to this query using Analysis for Office from Excel to see the data from this query. This connection is made through Insert Data source using SAP logon and my credentials.

My question is -  Can I open the Query in Visual Studio like a Project? I mean not just see the data without any relationships, but to see the table and design views? How can I import the Model into Visual Studio?

Thank you

Comment: Where data come from - SAP BW? If this is the case, you should go to SAP design instruments like SPRO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [Microsoft BW Connector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/microsoft-connector-for-sap-bw?view=sql-server-ver15) installed which is a part of [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2016 Feature Pack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52676) and also you need [BI Developer Extensions for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=BIDSHelper.BIDeveloperExtensionsVS2017) (SSDT) which you supposedly already have.

Just select [SAP BW Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/sap-bw-source?view=sql-server-2017) as a data source in Visual Studio and follow the instructions from [this guide](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/08/05/how-to-connect-microsoft-ssis-with-sap-hana/). Finally you should have something like this

[image]